# T-SQL: find an empty column

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

In my table there are 10 columns used for storing "items" (game server). When an user picks the item up, it should loop through columns 0-9 (with names "I0".."I9") and returns once the column in current row is empty. I cannot figure out how to do it on the SQL server side.
I can only think of IF EXISTS for each column but that is not really good.. Glad for any help! Thanks

Comment: This looks a lot like a database design flaw. Instead of X columns you should use X rows to store items.

Comment: Why is the EXISTS check for each column not good?  That is essentially want you want to do, and probably the shortest route for SQL Server to find the records.  Any other sort of cursor-based iteration or dynamic sql is probably event less good.

Comment: The problem statement is unclear. What is the expected behaviour once an empty column is found? What do rows contain?

Comment: What if you need to increase the item count, to let's say 20 items? Add another 10 columns and change every query that uses I0..I9? Normalize the database, and those issues tend to go away.

Answer (score 5):

Maybe it's better to have table `items (user_id, item_id)` and limit the count to 10 for each user?

It seems for me to be a good way to normalize your table and solve your problem. Also your table structure becomes more flexible - you can increase or decease the limit dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me like you're trying to find an empty column for a specified user (row).  And, an empty column contains NULL.  Assuming this is correct and ignoring the concerns about proper design, here's something that will return the number of the first column that contains a NULL value.

```
SELECT CASE
    WHEN I0 IS NULL THEN 0
    WHEN I1 IS NULL THEN 1
    WHEN I2 IS NULL THEN 2
    WHEN I3 IS NULL THEN 3
    WHEN I4 IS NULL THEN 4
    WHEN I5 IS NULL THEN 5
    WHEN I6 IS NULL THEN 6
    WHEN I7 IS NULL THEN 7
    WHEN I8 IS NULL THEN 8
    WHEN I9 IS NULL THEN 9
  END AS NextColumn
FROM MyTable
WHERE UserID = 'Me'
;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT COALESCE(I0, I1, I2, I3, I4, I5, I6, I7, I8, I9) AS FirstNotNull
FROM MyTable
```